# Drupal9 JSON:API filtering on Paragraphs content

Tags: drupal, json-api

I have a json api endpoint that I can search on title that contains a term:
/jsonapi/node/article?filter[title][operator]=CONTAINS&filter[title][value]=search term

But I also have a Paragraphs field that I need to use in the filter, so if the title or Paragraphs field contain the search term then return the article

I have tried various way of filtering against the Paragraph field but can't get anything back:
filter[paragraph_field][operator]=CONTAINS&filter[paragraph_field][value]=search term

I'm sure this is possible as one of the Features of Paragraphs is stated as 'Entities, so: exportable field bases/instances, usable in Search API, usable in Views'

Comment: Are you able to add the paragraph to advanced->relations within the display form of the view? If so you can add a filter based on that relation AFAIK

Comment: hi @johnSmith, sorry I should have made it clearer but I am using the JSON:API which does not use Views

Comment: my bad, my short research only showed up the option to filter json:api for a specific reference and not for field-values of the referenced entities itself ... which is a little disapointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it, there was a hint in the error; it's a matter of getting the path correct in the key:

```
?filter[field_paragraphs.field_body.value][operator]=CONTAINS
&filter[field_paragraphs.field_body.value][value]=search term
```